# Bundler locked loofah, without reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, feedzirra

So I want to use feedzirra in my rails app. Feedzirra uses loofah gem. When I had only feedzira gem specified in Gemfile it installed loofah 1.0.0. But loofah 1.0.0 have some problems with utf-8 encoding. So I wanted upgrade and changed gemfile to

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.github.com'

gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.4.7'
gem 'loofah', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'feedzirra'
```

But now Bundler tells me that loofah is locked to 1.0.0

```
You have requested:
  loofah ~> 1.2.1

The bundle currently has loofah locked at 1.0.0.
Try running `bundle update loofah
```

Ok, but bundle update loofah throws this and I'm confused, it doesn't tell me anything...

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "loofah":
  In Gemfile:
    loofah (~> 1.2.1) ruby

    loofah (1.0.0)
```

Comment: So it appears feedzira has really locked loofah 1.0.0, but I can't find where....

Answer (score 0):

I removed all gems and run bundle install again, this time without any problems